# Access violation exception in 64bit MFC version

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, 64-bit

I am trying to port a 32bit application to 64 bit. The calculations appear to run correctly, but I cannot configure the views properly. I am using MFC, C++ and OpenGL, Intel 10.0.027 compiler inside VS2005 on a W7 x64 machine.

When the crash happens, I get the following message: "First-chance exception at 0xffffffff8043b1b6 in 3DApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation at location 0xffffffff8043b1b6" and this is the stack trace:

```
ffffffff8043b1b6()  
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()  + 0x11d bytes 
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  + 0x12a bytes   
3DApp.exe!AfxInternalPumpMessage()  Line 183    C++
3DApp.exe!CWinThread::PumpMessage()  Line 896   C++
3DApp.exe!CWinThread::Run()  Line 625 + 0x13 bytes  C++
```

**NOTE PLEASE** why is UserCallWinProcCheckWow called, I thought Wow suffix was only for emulating 32 bit applications on 64 bit computer

Obviously, somewhere a 64 bit pointer gets treated as a 32 bit pointer, but I cannot pin point where that happens. I loaded debug symbols from microsoft, which show the top of the call stack.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Leon

**EDIT**

The code calling DispatchMessage is:

```
    if (pState->m_msgCur.message != WM_KICKIDLE && !AfxPreTranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur)))
{
    ::TranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur));
    ::DispatchMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur));
}
```

The pointers of pState appear to be 64 bit at this stage.

State of pState->m_msgCu:

- pState->m_msgCur    {msg=0x00000022 wp=0x0000000000000000 lp=0x0000000000000000}    tagMSG
- hwnd    0x0000000000020416 {unused=0x00000000 } HWND__ *
      message 0x00000022  unsigned int
      wParam  0x0000000000000000  unsigned __int64
      lParam  0x0000000000000000  __int64
      time    0x000f3967  unsigned long
- pt  {x=0x0000030f y=0x00000356} tagPOINT

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just fixed an issue with the same behavior. The bug was in passing parameters to SetWindowLongPtr( GWLP_WNDPROC ), pointer to WndProc was improperly casted to LONG instead of correct LONG_PTR. This way, bad pointer to WndProc was put into internal OS WND struct, so any following call to the HWND's WndProc crashed.

Comment: This. F*** `SetWindowLongPtr(... (LONG) pWndPrc`. `(LONG_PTR)`fixes it. Your answer just saved me a good deal of work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the the problem is happening in a call to [DispatchMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) inside MFC. It would be helpful if you'd post the parameters to this call.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. The code calling DispatchMessage is :
if (pState->m_msgCur.message != WM_KICKIDLE && !AfxPreTranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur)))
 {
  ::TranslateMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur));
  ::DispatchMessage(&(pState->m_msgCur));
 }

Comment: @Leon: Yeah, I've seen the code in question before. I'm after the arguments that were passes in the call to DispatchMessage in this function. Use the debugger to find the contents of "State->m_msgCur".

Comment: is this what you mean?-  pState->m_msgCur {msg=0x00000022 wp=0x0000000000000000 lp=0x0000000000000000} tagMSG
+  hwnd 0x0000000000020416 {unused=0x00000000 } HWND__ *
  message 0x00000022 unsigned int
  wParam 0x0000000000000000 unsigned __int64
  lParam 0x0000000000000000 __int64
  time 0x000f3967 unsigned long
+  pt {x=0x0000030f y=0x00000356} tagPOINT

Comment: sorry, I cannot place code neatly inside comments. I'll append it to the question

Answer (score 0):

OK, 0x00000022 is the [WM_CHILDACTIVATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632616%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mesasage. It takes no parameters, so it can't be a problem with those. The only other possible cause that springs to mind is that the window prodedure isn't valid. For example, the DLL that contains it could have been unloaded or the window could have been subclassed with an invalid address.

Comment: you should consider editing your previous answer instead of starting a new one.

Comment: @YeenFei: Ok. Will do next time.

Comment: @Steve, the expections happens for a number of message type. It initially started happening with WM_MOVE. As I stripped back some functionality, it now happens on WM_CHILDACTIVE.

Comment: @Steve, is user32.dll the correct version? it is loaded from 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll' which I have read should be the 64 bit version. The 32 bit version is in SystemWow folder?

Comment: @Lean: As the WM_CHILDACTIVE message has no parameters it looks like the problem is in dispatching the message to the window procedure. Off the top of my head I can only think of a few likely causes (I listed them in this post). Given the nature of the problem and message would cause a crash.

Comment: @Leon: I believe the names have been preserved for compatability. It's a similar situation to the WPARAM issue:          http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/25/55850.aspx

Comment: @Steve-Thanks for that link. Can you understand why UserCallWinProcCheckWow is called. Isnt WOW just emulating 32 bit programs on 64 bit machine?

Comment: @Leon: UserCallWinProcCheckWow is an internal function. I'm guessing it's part of the plumbing that allows 32bit and 64bit applications to send (or post) window messages to each other.