# first chance exception thrown from translatemessage() api of window's user32.dll in 64 bit

Tags: c++, windows, windbg, usermode

There is a exception thrown from TranslateMessage() API of user32.dll. When i tried to analyze the exception using !analyze -v in windbg command, i got the following information. Can anyone help me decode the error

```
FAULTING_IP: 
+0
ffffffff`e85b6720 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: ffffffffe85b6720
   ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 2
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000008
   Parameter[1]: ffffffffe85b6720
Attempt to execute non-executable address ffffffffe85b6720

FAULTING_THREAD:  000000000000642c

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  CapGM.exe

ADDITIONAL_DEBUG_TEXT:  
You can run '.symfix; .reload' to try to fix the symbol path and load symbols.

MODULE_NAME: mfc100u

FAULTING_MODULE: 0000000077720000 ntdll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4df2cfdb

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000008

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER2:  ffffffffe85b6720

WRITE_ADDRESS:  ffffffffe85b6720 

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
mfc100u+2745a8
00000000`74eb45a8 488bf0          mov     rsi,rax

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
+2745a8
ffffffff`e85b6720 ??              ???

APP:  capgm.exe

IP_ON_HEAP:  ffffffffe85b6720
The fault address in not in any loaded module, please check your build's rebase
log at <releasedir>\bin\build_logs\timebuild\ntrebase.log for module which may
contain the address if it were loaded.

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 0000000077519bd1 to ffffffffe85b6720

STACK_TEXT:  
00000000`003bbb68 00000000`77519bd1 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`775172cb : 0xffffffff`e85b6720
00000000`003bbb70 00000000`775172cb : 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`e85b6720 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : USER32!TranslateMessageEx+0x2a1
00000000`003bbc30 00000000`77516829 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`003bbd78 000007fe`ecfede14 00000018`000000c8 : USER32!SetWindowTextW+0x277
00000000`003bbc90 00000000`777711f5 : 00000000`00000000 000007fe`ecfb0000 00000000`000003e9 00000000`0055055c : USER32!IsDialogMessageW+0x169
00000000`003bbcf0 00000000`7751041a : 00000000`77510397 00000000`003bc1a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`003bc1a8 : ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcher+0x1f
00000000`003bbd78 00000000`77510397 : 00000000`003bc1a8 00000000`00000000 00000000`003bc1a8 00000000`003bc1a8 : USER32!SendMessageTimeoutW+0x95a
00000000`003bbd80 00000000`775105d8 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 00000000`56000000 : USER32!SendMessageTimeoutW+0x8d7
00000000`003bc0f0 00000000`77510880 : 00000000`00000148 00000000`56000000 00000000`003bc3d9 00000000`74f0c6b0 : USER32!SendMessageTimeoutW+0xb18
00000000`003bc240 00000000`74eb45a8 : 00000000`00582960 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000320 00000000`00900000 : USER32!CreateWindowExW+0x70
00000000`003bc2c0 00000000`74eac377 : 00000000`0c07e510 00000000`0c07e510 00000000`00000000 00000000`00900000 : mfc100u+0x2745a8
00000000`003bc340 00000000`74eac4b6 : 00000000`0055055c 00000000`0c07e510 00000000`56000000 00000000`00000318 : mfc100u+0x26c377
00000000`003bc400 000007fe`e8ba1316 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`003be330 00000000`0bee1a80 00000000`0c07e510 : mfc100u+0x26c4b6
00000000`003bc470 000007fe`ecfdaab6 : ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`ffffffff 00000000`00000000 : FrontEnd!FrontWindowFactory<dFrontWindow>::create+0x136
```

i understood that translate message is trying to access some wrong address but how do i fix it?

Comment: This would be significantly easier to dissect if you actually followed the advice given multiple times in the dump; namely wiring symbols up to get a better picture of this

Comment: I guess it requires user32.pdb file which i dont have. Basically i dont have windows PDBs. All the other pdbs have already been loaded

Comment: There better be symbols for user32.pdb. If you're using WinDbg for this, make sure the MS symbol store is in your symbols path. Information on how to do that [**can be found here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Is it a first chance exception or an actual unhandled exception?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: unhandled exception.

Comment: Checking `uf USER32!TranslateMessageEx+0x2a1` on my machine brings me into `USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x190` to the instruction `call qword ptr [rsp+0C8h]`. Is this a 32-bit application? Perhaps related to your problem is this [Access Violation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138156/access-violation-exception-in-64bit-mfc-version)

Comment: Fix your symbols and reanalyse:  `.symfix;.reload;!analyze -v` and edit your post with the updated and correct output

Comment: @EdChum - I'm trying to learn the ropes a bit so I wonder if you could verify my comment. Could it make sense or am I completely off the mark? *(and why?)* Thanks in advance.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers this is not a 32-bit application as the addresses are all 64-bit `00000000`003bbb68` the accent is just an output nicety so you can see the 32-bit boundary. Also the stack register is `rsp` rather than `esp` which it would be for 32-bit. Your link is a possibility but I'd like to see corrected symbols

Comment: @EdChum - Thanks. I'll leave the comments as others might benefit from my mistakes ;)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: Originally, this application was a 32 bit application.Im trying to port it to 64 bit and im stuck with this exception.Now the application comes up in 64 bit but has some issues like the one mentioned above.

Comment: @Edchum : i tried the .symfix;.reload; option but it takes too long and leaves my windbg hanged for a long duration till i forcefully stop it.Will try again and let u know the results soon

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers: U were right.. After installing the corresponding pdbs when i debugged the application. It does point to USER32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x190 to the instruction call qword ptr [rsp+0C8h] which means the pointer to call back function is wrong or is been truncated to 32- bit (0xffffffff`e85b6720)This means somewhere during conversion from 32 bit to 64 bit,the value has been truncated.
For ex consider this
LONG_PTR value=0x0000007e`e85b6720
long my_value1=value
LONG_PTR final_value=value1
now final_value contains 0xffffffff`e85b6720
How do i proceed to find where the error is

Comment: @user3462791 - My first try would be to dump the stack and look for where `e85b6720` changes from `xxxxxxxxe8b6720` to `ffffffffe8b6720`. You could use `dds poi(@$teb+0x10) poi(@$teb+0x08)` to dump the stack en get a notion of where you are codewise. If the value doesn't get passed through the stack, you could search for it in memory but I'm not proficient enough with WinDbg to know what to do next...

Answer (score 1):

The Problem is Fixed. The error was in SetWindowLongPtr(). This is 64 bit variant of SetWindowLong().Though the function was changed but the value of its wriiten was still captured in long variable.Changing it to LONG_PTR fixed the issue. Now the address doesnot get truncated and the corresponding user routine gets called.

Thanks for everyone's help :)

Comment: How did you end up finding the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned above - first thing to do will be to get the right symbols.

Microsoft exposes public symbols for its windows binaries. That will give a much better idea of what is going wrong.

Now, looking at the !analyze output that you have shared and the signature of TranslateMessage.

`BOOL WINAPI TranslateMessage(
  _In_  const MSG *lpMsg
);`

My best guess would be that you are not validating that `lpMsg` is a genuine input. Can you paste the input passed ?

General, rule of thumb public APIs that have been around for a while is very well tested. So if something is going wrong there, it will be a good idea to check what input our program is passing to it :)